# PostgreSQL join: delete records present in one table, but not another

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-delete

I have a Drupal website embedding a Flash game.

The registered **website users** are listed in the **drupal_users** table - here the list of those, registered over a week ago:

```
# select uid, created from drupal_users where 
      to_timestamp(created) < (now() - interval '7 days') limit 5;
 uid  |  created
------+------------
 9903 | 1300257067
 9904 | 1300259929
 9750 | 1299858284
 9751 | 1299858603
 8083 | 1285514989
(5 rows)
```

The Flash **game users** are listed in another table - the **pref_users** and have "DE" string prepended to their id:

```
# select id from pref_users where id like 'DE%' limit 5;
   id
--------
 DE9054
 DE9055
 DE9056
 DE9057
 DE9058
(5 rows)
```

I would like to get rid of the (probably SPAM robots) users who registered at my website over a week ago, but still haven't played the Flash game. I.e. I'd like to **delete drupal_users records, which are not present in the pref_users table**.

At the same time I'd prefer not to do something like:

```
# delete from drupal_users where 
    to_timestamp(created) < (now() - interval '7 days') and
    'DE'||uid not in (select id from pref_users where id like 'DE%');
```

because I'm not sure, how big the select statement above is allowed to be (maybe there is a limit? I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.7 and CentOS 5.5/64 bit. Before Drupal7 I was using phpBB3 and sometimes I had seen such kind of SQL-statements fail while deleting old forum posts from phpBB3 admin console).

So my question is, if the statement above can be rewritten as [some kind of SQL-join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting a delete as a SQL join is not possible, AFAIK.
But why don't you like

```
delete from drupal_users where 
to_timestamp(created) < (now() - interval '7 days') and
'DE'||uid not in (select id from pref_users where id like 'DE%');
```

The size of this statement is static (you don't generate any dynamic SQL here), so this is a perfectly valid approach, and should run pretty fast (if that's what you are concerned about).

Comment: Because I was hitting some PostgreSQL limit (don't remember which one, sorry) with a similar statement "delete from table1 where id in (select id from table2)" when deleting old forum posts from phpBB3 ACP.

Comment: PostgreSQL has a (non-standard) extension to DELETE where you can specify another table with USING, but I guess this is not possible here (since - if I understand USING correctly - it always performs an inner join). But you might want to check this out for yourself.

Comment: Ok and do you think adding distinct to the (select id from pref_users where id like 'DE%') is a good idea?

Comment: No, since it's superfluous - DISTINCT is never necessary for a IN / EXISTS subquery. It might even slow down your query (because the optmizer will have to remove duplicates twice - once for your DISTINCT and once for IN).

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get acceptable performance using a `NOT IN` when dealing with joins across tables with millions of records.
Instead I wrote the equivalent of:

```
alter table drupal_users add column dont_delete boolean;
```

then

```
update drupal_users set dont_delete = true from pref_users 
where 'DE'||drupal_users.uid = pref_users.id.
```

This will cease to be valid as soon as new drupal_users are created, but because you are only deleting records older than 7 days, it's ok.
Finally, verify your records and issue:

```
delete from drupal_users where dont_delete is null
  and to_timestamp(drupal_users.created) < (now() - interval '7 days');
```

clean up with:

```
alter table drupal_users drop column dont_delete;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the scenario where you say there is some postgresql limit:

```
create table t0 (id int primary key);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "t0_pkey" for table "t0"
CREATE TABLE

create table t1 (id int primary key);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "t1_pkey" for table "t1"
CREATE TABLE

insert into t0 (id) 
select * from generate_series(1, 100000, 2);
INSERT 0 50000

insert into t1 (id) 
select * from generate_series(2, 100000, 2);
INSERT 0 50000

select * from t0 order by id limit 3;
 id 
----
  1
  3
  5
(3 rows)

select * from t1 order by id limit 3;
 id 
----
  2
  4
  6
(3 rows)
```

Now I delete all rows from t0 that don't exist in t1 (all of them):

```
delete from t0
where id not in (select id from t1);
```

And it works

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, using an EXISTS subquery:

```
delete from drupal_users D
where to_timestamp(created) < (now() - interval '7 days')
and not exists (select 1 from pref_users P where P.id = 'DE' || D.uid);
```